# How can I force one block of code to wait until an API call finishes in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, asynchronous

I am making an API call and want the code after the call to not run until the API call finishes.

I have a function, `this.api_call`, which calls an API and returns an array, `returnValue`, after the API call is complete.

```
let returnValue = this.api_call(data);

//This line should not run until returnValue has been set
this.otherFunction(returnValue[0], returnValue[1]);
```

How can I make just that one line wait before running? I want other code to still be able to run before the API call completes, it's just that one line that should wait.

Comment: `it's just that one line that should wait` -- to be clear, the surrounding context will return immediately (not wait for that line), but that line itself will wait? That's what `Promise` and `async`/`await` is for. If you want to block the surrounding context, that isn't possible. JS can only parallelize code via async, not block code execution in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's where Promises come in, If your function `this.api_call(data)` returns a Promise, you can then call the `then` function on it, with a callback, and this callback will be run only after the promise has resolve.

```
this.api_call(data).then((returnValue) => {
    this.otherFunction(returnValue[0], returnValue[1]);
});
```

You can also use [RxJS's observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable), which lets you alter your data before returing it using `pipe` function. If you are using observable, make sure your `subscribe` to your observable otherwise it will never be fired. 
If your `this.api_call(data)` function is returning an observable ( usually the case if you use Angular), use it like that:

```
this.api_call(data).subscribe((returnValue) => {
    this.otherFunction(returnValue[0], returnValue[1]);
});
```

There is also a way to use `async`  / `await` keywords but i'm not a pro in this concept so i'll let somebody else answer that.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be less complicated than using async/await, so I'm not sure why await is the more common suggestion.

Comment: It usually come down to people not wanting to deal with chained function call. I personnally enjoy it and find it more clean but not everybody agrees with that. @Joe123

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve it, the simplest one is async / await syntax of Promise:

```js
async function myAsyncFunction(): Promise<void> {
    let returnValue = await this.api_call(data);

    this.otherFunction(returnValue[0], returnValue[1]);
}
```

`this.api_call(data)` have to return a `Promise<ArrayLike<...>>` in your example.

Comment: Your function doesn't have any `return` statement, is it really returning a promise ?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes. When a function is async and it has no return, it's type is `Promise<void>`.